# Dart Language: Get URI query parameters without server port

Tags: dart, uri, port

The Dart documentation focuses on processing HTTP requests over a specific server port. So if the server is listening on port 4123, you should be fine by sending GET, POST or other requests to an URI like:

```
http://www.somedomain.com:4123/?q=something
```

However, query parameters sent to the server/domain without specifying the server port will not be handled, like:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/?q=something
```

So what should I do to handle query parameters sent to my server (address/domain) without specifying a server port?

**EDIT 1:**

Some possible solution would be to implement an "URI checker" at the main method and retrieve the query (if it's present), like so:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {

    // Gets the URI in order to check it for any parameters.
    var uri = Uri.parse(window.location.href);

    // Check for the parameter presence in the URI.
    if (uri.queryParameters["q"] != null) {

        // Gets the parameter content and stores it.
        var queryParamContent = uri.queryParameters["q"];

        // Check if the parameter content is empty or not.
        if (queryParamContent.isNotEmpty) {
            // Do something with the query parameter.
        } else {
            // Warn the user about the empty query.
        }
    } else {
        // There's nothing interesting to check in the URI.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work without a port create a bug report at http://dartbug.com/new.

As a workaround you can use port 80 which is the default value when no specific port is set.

Comment: Günter, isn't it the expected behavior of the application? I mean, if the server is listening on port "4123", only requests sent to this port will be handled. What I'm looking for is to make my server-side application handle those queries sent to my address without the port specification. Is there any other way to do that other than setting the listening port to 80?

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to accomplish.
There is no request without a port. If you don't set the port the default port for the protocol is used (every standardized protocol has a default port). For HTTP the default port is 80.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But the problem is that setting the server to listen on port 80 will probably make it work even more, because of normal GET requests sent from usual browser functions, for instance. And what about port reservation? I thought that it wouldn't be possible to listen to port 80 on a server which is already running a web server. What would be great is some way to read the query parameters from the "port-less" URI and route it to the server as an internal request. Is that possible or too much workaround?

Comment: When you already have a server listening at port 80 no other server can listen at this port. What you can do is to set up a forwarding server/proxy on port 80 that forwards requests depending on the URL to servers listening on other ports. This is used regularily but this topic has nothing to do with software development. You can look at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/, or some other server management forum for more detailed information.

Comment: Günter, I've added some possible solution. What do you think about it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to accomplish. I thought you want to access a server and pass query parameters the `Uri` class would help. `var uri = Uri.parse(window.location.href); print(uri.queryParameters['q']);`

Comment: I need to improve my explanation skills, haha! I want the application working like YouTube does with video alias, where /watch?v=abcd123 takes you to a specific page (in YouTube's case, a video). But I don't want the port to be shown on the address bar, so this is why I have to process it internally (get the parameter and then send it to the server via HttpRequest). PS: I've edited the question to implement URI var. I had totally forgotten about that.

Comment: I suggest to use a routing package. This is exactly what they are for. Here you can find a simple example how I use the route_hierarchical package with Polymer https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_polymer_routing.
They help to synchronize the application state with the browser URL while keeping the browser forward/backwards buttons intact. You can do this manually using `hashChanged` event and `pushState()` but it is cumbersome.